# How to insert a Drupal form within the body of the website?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-forms

I'm editing a page and I want there to be a drupal form in the page.

I know how to make drupal forms, but whenver I edit the 'body' block and insert some php, it displays outside of the template

Is there some parameter I can insert like

```
 $output = drupal_get_form(my_form, 'node 1')
```

or something?

Thanks in advance

$output = drupal_get_form(contact_form, 'node 1');

drupal_render($output);

```
function contact_form($form_state) {
    $form['firstname'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield', 
        '#title' => t('Title of Notice'), 
        '#size' => 30,
        '#required' => TRUE
    $form['lastname'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield', 
        '#title' => t('Title of Notice'), 
        '#size' => 30,
        '#required' => TRUE
    $form['email_from'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield', 
        '#title' => t('Title of Notice'), 
        '#size' => 30,
        '#required' => TRUE
    $form['telephone'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield', 
        '#title' => t('Title of Notice'), 
        '#description' => t("Optional"),
        '#size' => 30,
        '#required' => TRUE
    $form['comments'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textarea', 
        '#title' => t('Title of Notice'), 
        '#size' => 30,
        '#required' => TRUE
    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Submit'),
    );
    return $form; 
};

function contact_form_validate($form, $form_state) {
    $error_message = "";
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
    if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
        $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }
    if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
        $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }
    if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
        $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }
    if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
        $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }
    if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
        died($error_message);
    }
};

function contact_form_submit($form, $form_state) {
    // build the body of the email  
    $body = "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."<br />"."Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."<br />"."Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."<br />"."Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."<br />"."Comments: ".clean_string($comments);

    //send
    $message = array(
        'to' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'subject' => $email_subject,
        'body' => $body,
        'headers' => array(
            'From' => $email_from,
            'To' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            'Subject' => $email_subject,
            );
drupal_mail_send($message);
};
```

I added my whole code because the answers I've gotten didnt work for me.

Comment: What do you mean by body block, do you mean the body field of a node?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use

drupal_render($output)

This is a good post that at explains https://drupal.org/node/224333#unrendered

I've just created a module with the following code, your arrays weren't closed properly

```
function contact_test_form($form) {    
    $form['firstname'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield', 
        '#title' => t('Title of Notice'), 
        '#size' => 30,
        '#required' => TRUE,
        );
    $form['lastname'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield', 
        '#title' => t('Title of Notice'), 
        '#size' => 30,
        '#required' => TRUE,);
    $form['email_from'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield', 
        '#title' => t('Title of Notice'), 
        '#size' => 30,
        '#required' => TRUE,);
    $form['telephone'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield', 
        '#title' => t('Title of Notice'), 
        '#description' => t("Optional"),
        '#size' => 30,
        '#required' => TRUE,);
    $form['comments'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textarea', 
        '#title' => t('Title of Notice'), 
        '#size' => 30,
        '#required' => TRUE,);
    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Submit'),
    );
    return $form; 
};

function contact_form_validate($form, $form_state) {
    $error_message = "";
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
    if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
        $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }
    if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
        $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }
    if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
        $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }
    if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
        $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }
    if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
        died($error_message);
    }
};

function contact_form_submit($form, $form_state) {
    // build the body of the email  
    $body = "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."<br />"."Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."<br />"."Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."<br />"."Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."<br />"."Comments: ".clean_string($comments);

    //send
    $message = array(
        'to' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'subject' => $email_subject,
        'body' => $body,
        'headers' => array(
            'From' => $email_from,
            'To' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            'Subject' => $email_subject,
            ),);
drupal_mail_send($message);
};
```

Then add this into a node body using php content filter

```
<?php 
$output = drupal_get_form('contact_test_form');
return drupal_render($output);
?>
```

Comment: I added the code that you suggested and I still don't get any output within the body of my page. I've also edited my question with the all of my code so you can check. I get an error in the logs [PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting ')' in /var/www/html/includes/common.inc(1743) : eval()'d code on line 13, referer: http://xxxxxxxxxxxx/node/115/edit]

Comment: what theme are you using? try it with a default theme like Bartik

Comment: Not Quite. I just made the form into a module and then used hook_menu to put use it as a page.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you created this form with Webform...

If you just want to display the form at the end of the page, go to the form advance settings and click on *"available as block"*

Then on the block sections, add it to the *"main content section"* and configute the block.
Under *Show block on specific pages*, write the pages you want it to appear.

---

To print a block programatically

```
$block = module_invoke('webform', 'block_view', 'client-block-1'); //add your block id
print render($block['content']);
```